# Piping to ffmpeg fails - "pipe:: Not enough space"

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to write a script that can download a file from a webserver to memory, pipe it directly to the ffprobe module of ffmpeg, and return the file's details as determined by ffprobe. This is what I currently have:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def get_file(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    file = BytesIO(r.content).seek(0)
    return file

def get_info(file):
    p = Popen(["ffprobe", "-i", "-"], stdin=file, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    output = p.communicate()[1].decode("utf8")
    return output
```

Here is a comparison between outputs for a file loaded with open():

```
ffprobe version N-66931-gbbd8c85 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 17 2014 01:05:12 with gcc 4.9.1 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 10.100 / 54. 10.100
  libavcodec     56.  8.100 / 56.  8.100
  libavformat    56.  9.100 / 56.  9.100
  libavdevice    56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.106 /  5.  1.106
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    title           : Test File
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Test File
```

... and a file downloaded with get_file():

```
ffprobe version N-66931-gbbd8c85 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 17 2014 01:05:12 with gcc 4.9.1 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 10.100 / 54. 10.100
  libavcodec     56.  8.100 / 56.  8.100
  libavformat    56.  9.100 / 56.  9.100
  libavdevice    56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.106 /  5.  1.106
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
pipe:: Not enough space
```

At first, this appears like an issue with insufficient memory, but the files I'm working with are small (<10MB), so I don't think that's the issue. Apparently, though, I'm doing something wrong... could anyone give me any suggestions as to why piping would fail in this instance?

Comment: you get this failure running it on "Just" the command line? what about sending it to ffmpeg?

Comment: Sorry? These outputs were produced by piping files from python to ffprobe. The "Not enough space" warning occurs regardless of what audio file I attempt to use. The same audio file would be successfully processed if I download it, then run ffprobe, but I'd like to avoid writing to the disk.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this old question. I have found a plausible answer as to why this error happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this isn't a reproducible error, because I just went back, tried that same code, and it magically worked. I'm thinking that the 'Not enough space' error might have been caused by something memory-intensive going on at the time, preventing me from passing the file to ffmpeg. I don't recall the file I was attempting to load, but if it had been large, I can see how roadblocks might have been hit. It is undoubtedly wiser to stream data rather than attempt to load it all into memory at once.

Either way, everything is copacetic now!